# laravel-4 how to change date format

Tags: php, laravel-4, date-formatting

I want to insert a date into the clients table my db schema is below, I want to insert them into the `start_day` and `end_day` fields.

I have the below in validations in ClientController.php

If I insert a foreign `date_format` other than the one defined below I am thrown an error, but if I do insert the correct one it reverts to `0000-00-00`. But if I change the field `type` to `text` for example the `date_format` is inserted fine.

```
$rules = array(
        'project_name'       => 'required',
        'project_brief'      => 'required',
        'start_day' =>  array('required', 'date_format:"m-d-Y"'),
        'end_day'   => array('required', 'date_format:"m-d-Y"')
    );
```

I'm not sure where the problem lies to be honest. I've even tried to convert the time doing the below:

```
$start_day_old = Input::get('start_day');
$start_day = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($start_day_old));
$project = new Project;
$project->start_day = $start_day
$project->save();
```

However the results were the same. Does anyone know how I can rectify this issue?

[image: Clients DB Schema]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't insert a date formated as `dd-mm-yyyy` in `mysql`'s `date` field, it should be `yyyy-mm-dd`, so in your code here

```
$start_day = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($start_day_old));
```

Change it to

```
$start_day = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($start_day_old));
```

So, if a date is `15-10-2010` then it'll become `2010-10-15` and it's a valid date for `date` field in the `mysql` database.

Comment: ahh ok I see, so say when I print this data out from the database I can then use this `$start_day = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($start_day_old));` to convert to the format I want to see it in?

Comment: @gutigrewal, Yes, exactly, you can convert it to your choice of format.